# Alternate page containing the canonical page tag on ghost with amp enabled

Tags: amp-html, google-search, ghost-blog, canonical-link

I have blog on ghost with enabled AMP - Google Accelerated Mobile Pages.

On page: https://preciselab.io/json-merge-patch I see

```
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://preciselab.io/json-merge-patch/" />
    <link rel="amphtml" href="https://preciselab.io/json-merge-patch/amp/" />
```

and on https://preciselab.io/json-merge-patch/amp there is

```
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://preciselab.io/json-merge-patch/" />
```

It seems to be correct for me, but on https://search.google.com/search-console i see problem

> Alternate page containing a valid canonical page tag

Comment: What page does Google say is the alternate?  It could be completely unrelated to your link tags.

Comment: This is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Please [edit] the question to address the points that need to be clarified, then re-ask it on [webmasters.se] and delete it here.